# C# MVC - Get UserId from Session array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get the current logged in user identity through the Session array declared as below:

```
           if (user != null)
            {

                string[] UserProfile = new string[4];
                UserProfile[0] = Convert.ToString(user.UserID);
                UserProfile[1] = user.FirstName;
                UserProfile[2] = user.LastName;
                UserProfile[3] = Convert.ToString(user.UserType);
                Session["UserProfile"] = UserProfile;
```

I cant get the syntax to retrieve UserId from the Session in another controller. 
Appreciate any help... thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] userProfile = Session["UserProfile"] as string[];
string id = userProfile[0];
```

Comment: hi, i get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @user834754, that's probably because you haven't stored anything into the session before trying to access it or you are trying to access it from some part of the code which simply doesn't have access to the session or the session cookie was not sent by the client.

Comment: Hi, actually the session declaration is at AccountController, while I need to access the session from another controller. Any idea how can i do that??

Comment: @user834754, there shouldn't be any problem accessing the session cross controllers. Just make sure that you first go through the first controller in order to set the session before going to the second.